How do I replace text in a word document table using information from an excel file?
I have a template where I am trying to replace certain text with information from excel. The problem is that once I have replaced and saved the file, the conditions I have set no longer apply and all files are saved with the same information from the same excel row.
I also tried duplicating the word file with docx but the format was all jumbled up.
I run a loop on the function below, but every single word document table has all the same information from the same row.
Here is my code:
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd


def replace_and_save(excel_file, word_file, output_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

    doc = Document(word_file)
    table = doc.tables[0]

    for row_index, excel_row in df.iterrows():
        name = excel_row[2]
        sex = excel_row[3]
        nationality = excel_row[4]
        passport_num = excel_row[6]

        #This gives different information for each row
        print(name, sex, nationality, passport_num)

        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if "<Name>" in run.text:
                            run.text = run.text.replace("<Name>", name)
                        if "<Passport>" in run.text:
                            run.text = run.text.replace("<Passport>", passport_num)
                        if "<Nationality>" in run.text:
                            run.text = run.text.replace("<Nationality>", nationality)
                        if "<Sex>" in run.text:
                            run.text = run.text.replace("<Sex>", sex)

    doc.save(output_file)


With your nested loops, for each excel row you update ALL cells in doc with the info from that excel row; so in the end doc will feature info from the last excel row everywhere.

Use VBA?

@Swifty I'm sorry if I was not clear in my post. The FIRST row of the excel replaced the required places in the word doc. This is because it can no longer find "" and other texts since it has already been replaced. I want to know if there are ways to go around this problem. I tried duplicating the word doc but the formatting is all jumbled up. What else can I do?

@MT1 I would like to but I have never used it and would have to start learning it from 0. Can I duplicate a word doc in a loop with VBA?

Get started with the Excel Hello World macro here

this code works in MS Access VBA code to substitute values in a Word document so should give you a start with learning VBA.

I wouldn't learn a new language to solve this :-) look at @Swifty comment, he's right there is something to change in the logic of the code depending on what your tables in Word and Excel look like.

@ShinJira: I stand corrected (it would replace with the 1st row, not the last), but still your nested loop logic is off; that said, your goal isn't perfectly clear; you should provide a short example (a few rows of the excel, and an excerpt from the word) along with your desired output.
